# Mantle issue - MTLValueTransformer won't transform an NSNumber to an int

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, github-mantle

I'm using Mantle to successfully transform values in my model - but this one comes back with the error: `Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(NSNumber *__strong)' to parameter of type 'MTLValueTransformerBlock' (aka 'id (^)(__strong id)')`:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)numDownvotesJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^(NSNumber *number) {
        return [number intValue];
    } reverseBlock:^(int value) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:value];
    }];
}
```

This similar transform works fine:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)longitudeJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^(NSNumber *number) {
        return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[number decimalValue]];
    } reverseBlock:^(NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[decimalNumber doubleValue]];
    }];
}
```

Not understanding the difference here.

Comment: It seems to me that it requires you to return an object (`id`). `int` is a primitive, not an object.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from the project's maintainer: "Transformers must operate upon objects. You don't need to do anything for an NSNumber going to a primitive property, because Key-Value Coding takes care of that automatically."